# PHP: What is the best method to SQL query an array? (if you can)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Consider this:

One mySQL database that has tables and rows and data within it.

One array that has the same data.

Now normally, I would have a query like this for mySQL `SELECT * FROM 'table' WHERE name LIKE '%abc%'`

But I want to perform that same query on the array, without having to insert it yet. The only method that comes to mind is using [array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php), but the syntax is different and the method is convoluted.

Is there a shortcut here?

Comment: I highly doubt PHP has something similar to C# LINQ

Comment: There is a class that implements linq in PHP, http://phplinq.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples&referringTitle=Home

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't use SQL with arrays, but one way you could do your example is using `array_filter()`:

```
function like_abc($v) {
    return strstr($v['name'], 'abc') !== false;
}

$filtered = array_filter($yourArray, 'like_abc');
```

or if you are using PHP >= 5.3.0

```
$filtered = array_filter($yourArray, 
    function($v) { return strstr($v['name'], 'abc') !== false;});
```

See it in action on [ideone](http://ideone.com/GDEcY)

---

You can also try [PHPLinq](https://github.com/mkloubert/phpLINQ):

```
// UNTESTED CODE!
$yourArray = array (
    array('name' => 'abcd', 'age' => 20),
    array('name' => 'dacb', 'age' => 45),
    array('name' => 'aadd', 'age' => 32),
    array('name' => 'babc', 'age' => 11),
    array('name' => 'afgb', 'age' => 17),
);

$result = from('$people')->in($yourArray)
            ->where('$people["name"] => strstr($people["name"], "abc") !== false')
            ->select('$people');
```

Answer (score 1):

[CakePHP](http://www.cakephp.org) has a [Set::extract](http://api13.cakephp.org/class/set#method-Setextract) method that [uses XPath query strings](http://debuggable.com/posts/xpath-on-php-arrays-set-extract:48ca6265-258c-4032-b3ff-55b84834cda3) to find information. It's quite good and I think it shouldn't be too hard to use it without the rest of the CakePHP project.

Answer (score 1):

There is an [sql4array](http://absynthe.is.free.fr/sql4array/) class that allows you to use SQL to retrieve data from a PHP array, although I've never used it and can't comment on how good it is. The developers do acknowledge that it is slow though, and doesn't support the entirety of SQL syntax.

There is also, as has been mentioned, [PHPLinq](http://phplinq.codeplex.com/)

Personally, I'd be inclined to use array_filter()

Answer (score 0):

No there is no shortcut. You can't query an array with SQL. If your array contains the same data as your database table then it will be multidimensional as well which means that array_search is of no use. You will have to loop manually through the array and perform the like operation yourself, with preg_match for example.

```
$data = array(
  array('name' => 'foo abc bar', 'lorem' => 'ipsum'),
  array('name' => 'etc', 'lorem' => 'dolor')
);
$matches = array();
foreach ($data as $row) {
  if (preg_match('/^.*abc.*$/', $row['name']) {
    $matches[] = $row;
  }
}
```