# Dealing with a php array like an SQL Query, is that possible?

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms

I did my research and could not find anything related to what I am looking for.

I have a looped html form that includes 2 inputs as below:

```
#1
<input type="text" name="category[<?php echo $i; ?>][xml]" readonly="" value="<?php echo $categoryItem; ?>">
```

Which is related to this value in the same html form:

```
#2
<select name="category[<?php echo $i; ?>][pair]">';
    echo "<option value=" . $row['name'] . ">" . $row['name'] . "</option>";
```

The output array of the post method action is like below:

```
array(79) { 
[1]=> array(2) { ["xml"]=> string(10) "Kumbaralar" ["pair"]=> string(7) "Kumbara" }

[2]=> array(2) { ["xml"]=> string(18) "Mevlüt Şekerleri" ["pair"]=> string(10) "Şekerleme" } 
}
```

So what I need to get from the array is something like this sql query:

```
SELECT pair FROM array WHERE xml = "Mevlüt Şekerleri";
```

So I get the value "**Şekerleme**"

Can you let me know where should I look? I checked the manual and some topics but I think I have a lack of information regarding arrays.
Thanks in regards.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP: What is the best method to SQL query an array? (if you can)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539106/php-what-is-the-best-method-to-sql-query-an-array-if-you-can)

Comment: you can just simply use foreach. then put the `xml` value in each iteration to the test and use an if statement. if it matches, then simply echo the `pair`

Comment: Thanks Kevin, you helped me solve it.